# Python 2.7 : Lines from Textfile, multiple strings change

Tags: python-2.7

i got a simple problem, i cannot fix myself. after importing a text file, it looks like this:

```
 ['ADD_TEST xxxxxx"  ', ['set_tests_properties xxxxx ', 'set_tests_properties xxxx ']]
 ['ADD_TEST yyyyyy"  ', ['set_tests_properties yyyyy ', 'set_tests_properties yyyy ']]
```

I need it like this:

```
 ADD_TEST xxxxxx
 set_tests_properties xxxxx
 set_tests_properties xxxxx
 ADD_TEST yyyyyy
 set_tests_properties yyyyy
 set_tests_properties yyyyyy
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the code you used to import the text file?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print it to the consule, use string slicers.

```
a = ['ADD_TEST xxxxxx"  ', ['set_tests_properties xxxxx ', 'set_tests_properties xxxx ']]
b = ['ADD_TEST yyyyyy"  ', ['set_tests_properties yyyyy ', 'set_tests_properties yyyy ']]

print a[0]
print a[1][0]
print a[1][1]
print b[0]
print b[1][0]
print b[1][1]
```